# ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/mysite/mysite.log'

Tags: python, django

The production server is running right now and I just run the **python manage.py shell** in the VPS terminal but it says :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 558, in configure
handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 731, in 
configure_handler
    result = factory(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/handlers.py", line 150, in __init__
    BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, 
delay)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/handlers.py", line 57, in __init__
    logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1008, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1037, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'/var/log/mysite/mysite.log'
```

what can I do?

Comment: Adapt the permissions to that file so your process can write to it.

Comment: change your config and log path, or make a directory and log file in `/var/log/` and check permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have 2 options: 
1 - change the permissions of the file `/var/log/mysite/mysite.log` so other users can write to it. like `chmod 666 /var/log/mysite/mysite.log`

2 - run your shell script from `root` or the user that own `/var/log/mysite/mysite.log`

Comment: what is the role of 644? Is there any other options?

Comment: when I do **chmod 644 /var/log/mysite/mysite.log** it says : Operation not permitted

Comment: Should I do it by sudo?

Comment: just leave your answer and go!

Comment: you should change permissions with `sudo` . and change the permissions of the file to 666 , if you want to know about what each permission `number` represent - google : linux permissions.